# How to return excel file via ajax call using epplus

Tags: jquery, epplus

Trying to return an excel file via an ajax call but something isnt right.
The jquery code falls right into the error block.

mvc controller

```
   public ActionResult GetExceptionBillingExport(BillableStopSearchFilter bFilter)
    {
        var results = GetDataFromDatabase();
        
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(results, true);
            return File(package.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Report.xlsx");
        }
            
    }
```

jQuery method

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'controller-url-here',
    data: filter,
    beforeSend: function () {
       
    },
    complete: function () {
       
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = "Report.xlsx";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does the network tab help?

Comment: If anything here helps, please let me know in a comment.  Let me know which link is most helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669733/export-datatable-to-excel-with-epplus or https://stackoverflow.com/questions40517017/safari-adding-html-to-download-xlsx-using-epplus-jquery-filedownload-js or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764750/allow-client-to-download-excel-file or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670209/download-excel-file-via-ajax-mvc

Comment: I think I see the idea in those threads - to just write to the response within the server code, rather than have jquery do it?

Comment: Why not simply a link? `<a target="_blank" href="/controller-url-here">download excel</a>` of  if you want to use jquery: `location.href = '/controller-url-here'`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.  Key changes were:  (1) wrapping the response with Json, then (2) unpacking the array before creating the Blob

**jQuery**:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetBillingExport", "BillingExceptions")',
            data: searchFilterData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {

               
            },
            complete: function () {
                
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(response.FileContents);
                var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = "Report.xlsx";
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            },
            cache: false
        });
```

**controller**:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetBillingExport([FromBody] BillableStopSearchFilter searchFilterData)
{


    var results = GetDataFromDatabase(BillableStopSearchFilter);
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("BillingReport");
        sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(results, true);
        package.Save();
        var fileObject = File(package.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Report.xlsx");
        return Json(fileObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }




}
```