# Download zip without creating it in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compression

So,I have the following piece of code to create and download a zip file

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
   {
        using (var zipFile = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                //add more files
                archive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"C:\Temp\HugeFile.iso", "HugeFile.iso", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
            }
            return File(zipFile.ToArray(), "application/zip", "MyZip.zip");
        }
    }
```

It works fine but imagine I have a 10GB file,I will run out of memory.

If there I way to download the zip file while it is being created (so it's not taking much space in memory)?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I can write directly to the Response output or something like that...

Comment: Perhaps this is useful to you?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163448/mvc-controller-using-response-stream

Comment: @JonSkeet I get a NotSupportedException "Stream does not support seeking". I think I'll have to abandon the ZipArchive class,CreateEntryFromFile will create the entire record...

Comment: Or I'll probably create the file on disk and server that..